# Azure Web Site and Enterprise Library Logging

Tags: logging, azure, enterprise-library

I'm migrating existing ASP.NET Web site to Azure Web Site (not the Cloud Service). The Web Site uses EL for logging and exception handling. The issue is that I do not see my trace.log file when opening the Azure folder over FTP.

In IIS I had to set right permissions to the folder. But with Azure I do not have that option.

Does anyone uses logging to a file on Azure Web Site?

Comment: After a while the Trace.log appeared in the Web Site folder on the FTP. But I cannot download it - file is locked. In IIS you cannot delete it, but can read.

Comment: At this time I see two options:
1) Stop Web site to download the trace.log file
2) Direct tracing to the SQL Azure database (as Igorek suggested)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider saving your traces to a SQL Azure databases or implementing a trace provider that would save them to storage.  I do not believe you can use the file system on Azure Websites for anything but deployment

Comment: But you cannot use Diagnostic Monitor for Web Site. That's an issue.

Comment: That is correct.  Azure Diagnostics works only across Cloud Services